# How to find this button in selenium webdriver python?

Tags: python, button, selenium-chromedriver

how to find this button this is code, xpath doesn't work:

```
<button type="submit" data-module="tooltip" data-tooltip-config="addtocart" data-tooltip-content="#tooltip_addtocart" class="btn btn-orange-normal-plp addToCartClick product-tile__add-to-cart-CTA js--add-to-cart tooltipstered">
                                        <span class="product-tile__add-to-cart-icon icon-cart-white"></span>
                                    </button>
```

tnx

Comment: What does "xpath doesn't work" mean?

Comment: because is dynamic

Comment: So how do you identify the button you want? What is its defining characteristic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the relative Xpath to the button you want is:
//button[@type='submit']